# What is the last .mmm in the output of GETDATE()

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

```
Select GETDATE();
```

gives the output 2021-03-04 05:18:40.070 in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.mmm`

Can someone please tell me what the last .mmm represents?

Comment: It is milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

The `GETDATE()` function returns the current system timestamp as a `DATETIME` value without the database time zone offset. The last `mmm` in the output represents the `millisecond` which is the thousandth of a second.